# Why no rows in sys.dm_os_cluster_* on Availability Group?

Tags: sql-server-2016

Running into some issues with failovers on an Availability Group with two nodes and a file share witness.  I read a [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2012/09/07/how-it-works-sql-server-alwayson-lease-timeout/)  and then I tried to get the HealthCheckTimeout value from sys.dm_os_cluster_properties and no rows are returned.  My google skills are either not working well this morning or no one else has this problem.  I was able to get the values out of the Failover Cluster Manager.  I want to know why I get no rows out of the cluster DMVs when I do have a cluster.  I am assuming I have something set up wrong.

SQL SERVER 2016 SP1 CU2
WINDOWS SERVER 2016

I also don't get any rows on 2012 SQL and Server versions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dmv is for `Failover Cluster Instance` also known as FCI and not for `Windows Server Failover Cluster (WSFC)`.

> These properties are used to set the values that affect failure
>   detection, failure response time, and the logging for monitoring the
>   health status of the **SQL Server failover cluster** instance.

Details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-cluster-properties-transact-sql